# Is it possible to reuse a schema that is used for matching purposes?

Tags: karate

Is it possible to define a schema and then reuse it in multiple Feature files for use with with 'match' keyword? Or does the schema need to be re-defined in each Feature file?

Answer (score 2):

You can. Create the schema as a `*.json` file. Use the `read()` syntax to read it in multiple files.

Refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files